# Switching from Internal to dedicated graphics

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

My friend has a problem with his laptop and I'm trying to solve it for him but nothing seems to work.
The problem is as follows:
He got an old laptop for cheap and the previous owner replaced the graphics card from an Nvidia one (I don't recall which one) to an AMD 7970 and also switched from windows 7 to windows 10, but his laptop has Intel Integrated graphics which is preventing him from playing most games due to the fact that said games won't choose the right graphics card.

Now this is where the problem gets worse, I tried reinstalling the drivers but the computer freezes, and when I finally install them it says an error occurred and that I should contact AMD so I restore the system to a previous point and let it be. Then I also tried using AMD Crimson to change the graphics card that certain games use but to no avail since the software doesn't even open now... I also tried messing around with the Intel options and the AMD Crimson options back when it used to work but it was no use. So from my research all I'm left with is disabling it on the BIOS settings but I wanted to know if there was a different way to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

Id bet my 10 cents for the fact, that the reference drivers wont work. If the GPU is bought via Eurocom, thats where you should go and ask the drivers for. If Eurocom is down or slow, you might wanna find out the hardcore community for the drivers.